# How to add multiple request options to a swagger doc?

Tags: swagger, documentation, swagger-ui

My API has one handler for making payments. But mandatory fields may vary depending on a payment method. For example *credit card* and *sofort* have different mandatory fields and, therefore, a different request body. How can I display it in a swagger doc properly?

Comment: Do you use OpenAPI 2.0 or 3.0? Do you write your OpenAPI definition manually or generate it from code? If the latter, what language and library/framework do you use - Swashbuckle, Springdoc, Swagger-PHP, FastAPI, ...?